# How to use Reactstrap using CDN links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I'm using React with the CDN links, and have realized after a bit of a headache that I need to understand what is the global variable that has been configured for each library in order to use them.

For example in React-Redux, instead of:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
```

Which would result in:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react-redux". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I need to do:

```
export default ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)
```

Like I need to do with `React.Component`.

Which makes sense.

Now I'm searching for that global variable that has been defined for [Reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/). Unfortunately, the [demo link](http://output.jsbin.com/dimive/latest) for using CDN links is broken (I've already [opened an issue](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/2068)).

I searched the web and skimmed through the Reactstrap docs and I can't find anything.

I guessed it would be `Reactstrap.X` but that doesn't work.

I'm assuming this isn't a new request but I haven't found the answer (or it being asked), so I'd be happy if you can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using Reactstrap with CDN you should import stylesheet and Script then use `Reactstrap` for components.

**Example**:

```js
ReactDOM.render(<Reactstrap.Button>ReactStrap</Reactstrap.Button>, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reactstrap/4.8.0/reactstrap.min.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Ah, I see now that I mistakenly inserted `Reactstrap` to my own components. At least I was correct in assuming the global variable they defined :) (really, they should have it in their docs. Same goes for other libraries.. Took me hours to figure out the Redux one.)

Comment: Happy to help you :)